# How to select a particular cell from an 'array formula' result?

Tags: google-sheets

Take this formula:

`=GOOGLEFINANCE("PG", "high", DATE(2014, 4, 1))`

This formula returns an 'array result', meaning it generates a little table over multiple cells, like this:

[image]

The top-left cell pictured ('Date') is the one I wrote the formula in; the actual value I want is written to a cell below-right of it.

Is there some way I can wrap the formula with another formula, so I can just grab the exact cell that I want? I.e. so the cell I write my formula in will just contain "80.84", and no other nearby cells get overwritten. Something like:

`=GIVEMEONECELLFROMTHIS(GOOGLEFINANCE("PG", "high", DATE(2014, 4, 1), 'just the one at the bottom right pls')`

Answer (score 3):

Please try:

```
=index(GOOGLEFINANCE("PG", "high", DATE(2014, 4, 1)),2,2)
```